# cocos2d my image retina doesn't resize

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I have a problem in my application with cocos2d retina picture. When I run the application, the image retina is displayed, but it doesn't resize. 
Help me.

Comment: could you plz check your image size is as per apple guidline

Comment: the size of my image is correct: 640x960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check the your application enabled or not.

`if( ! [director_ enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )`

Second your image naming like this:

```
[sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"
```

image.png(normal - size is 320x480)

image-hd.png(retina - size is 640x960)

image-ipad.png(normal ipad - size is 1024x768)

image-ipadhd.png(ipad retina - size is 2048x1536)

Comment: I have the message: retina display not supported but I run on an iPhone 5. Yes my images have the correct name and correct size.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) for Launch image (required for all apps).

As iPhone 5 comes with different screen resolution in iOS6-sdk.

All you need to do is create a splash file named as `Default-568h@2x.png` with the resolution  `1136x640`, and put it in your Resources/iphone folder.

If you are updating application from older sdk to newer sdk then check you plist file and option to launch image.